# Can I write this xaml shorter?

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, binding

initially I had a window with lots of bindings like this one:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=DatabaseServer}" />
```

Now I have to add validation to each binding and I end with:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="DatabaseServer" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Utils:NotEmptyStringValidator />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Can this be written with less text? Otherwise I will end with a hard to maintain window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Binding Markup Extesnion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413.aspx)s page on MSDN:

> The following are properties of Binding that cannot be set using the
>   Binding markup extension/{Binding} expression form.
>
> ValidationRules : the property takes a generic collection of
>   ValidationRule objects. This could be expressed as a property element
>   in a Binding object element, but has no readily available
>   attribute-parsing technique for usage in a Binding expression. See
>   reference topic for ValidationRules.

So, no, there is not a more concise markup.

Unless you want to write your own markup extension?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the `Mode="TwoWay"` because it is that by default in WPF. Otherwise no, there is no way to write it more concisely when you are using ValidationRules declaratively like that.

If you are concerned about the XAML becoming hard to read due to the amount you have, most of the contructs (i.e. each opening node) should have a little +/- symbol in the margin which you can use to expand and collapse the code block.